# Django runserver under virtualenv using wrong version

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have Django 1.4.5 on my server and a working project.

I've used **virtualenv** to create an instance and installed Django 1.6.5 inside it `(pip install Django==1.6.5).`

If I simply run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Everything works fine and it starts a server using Django 1.6.5
But I have a file called **run_devenv.py**, which basically start my whole project using subprocesses. It starts server like this:

```
def run_devenv():
  processes = [
    ...
    ('webserver', subprocess.Popen([PYTHON, 'manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:%d' % HTTP_PORT, '--settings', os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']])),
    ...
  ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.access(settings.DEVENV_DIR, os.F_OK):
        setup_devenv()
    else:
        run_devenv()
```

And for some reason it uses Django 1.4.5 instead of 1.6.5.

Looks like it uses 1.4.5 installed in the system and omits the virtualenv instance with 1.6.5.

Can someone help with this?

**EDIT > Solution:**
My problem was this string (I didn't show it):

```
PYTHON = "/usr/bin/python"
```

It should look like this:

```
PYTHON = "path_to_your_virtualenv/bin/python"
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a path to the version of Django you want to run?

Comment: Right now I am figuring out how to use some unified value, so I don't hard-code name of virtualenv, looking for smth like 'sys.argv[0]' or '/usr/bin/env python'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the python binary within your virtualenv instead of your system one. From your code it looks like `PYTHON` is a variable pointing to your python binary? If so, you should just have to change it like this:

```
PYTHON = "/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/python"
```

Comment: Yes, this was the reason. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your script `run_devenv.py` is executable and has a declaration like `#!/bin/python` at the top. You can either alter which Python version runs the script or activate your virtualenv inside the script:

```
activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Answer (score 0):

the python path is the issue

if youre using linux/osx the following command should work, assuming you've activated the virtualenv

```
sudo /path/to/bin/python manage.py runserver
```